# SQL Query I'm having trouble with

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have these tables:

Highschooler ( ID, name, grade ) 
There is a high school student with unique ID and a given first name in a certain grade.

Friend ( ID1, ID2 ) 
The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2. Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is (456, 123).

Likes ( ID1, ID2 ) 
The student with ID1 likes the student with ID2. Liking someone is not necessarily mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Likes table, there is no guarantee that (456, 123) is also present.

If two students A and B are friends, and A likes B but not vice-versa, I want to remove the Likes tuple.

To start, I tried getting just the 2 tuples of non reciprocal likes who are friends, but I was unsuccessful...

I have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Likes
where Likes.ID1 in (
   select Likes.ID1 
   from Likes, Friend
   where Likes.ID1=Friend.ID1 
     and Likes.ID2=Friend.ID2
   ) 
AND NOT IN (
   SELECT Likes.ID1 
   FROM Likes L1, Likes L2, Friend
   WHERE L1.ID1=Friend.ID1 
     AND L2.ID2=Friend.ID2 
     AND L1.ID1 = L2.ID2 
     AND L1.ID2 = L2.ID1);
```

But it's not working.. I get an error.. Can someone please help me with this!

I actually have an image of the tables with the values in it but I can't post it because I need more than 10 reputation to do that...

EDIT:

Ok, I'm gonna put the tables in here because I'm still not getting the right result

```
Highschooler
ID  name    grade
1510    Jordan  9
1689    Gabriel 9
1381    Tiffany 9
1709    Cassand 9
1101    Haley   10
1782    Andrew  10
1468    Kris    10
1641    Brit    10
1247    Alexis  11
1316    Austin  11
1911    Gabriel 11
1501    Jessica 11
1304    Jordan  12
1025    John    12
1934    Kyle    12
1661    Logan   12


Friend
ID1 ID2
1510    1381
1510    1689
1689    1709
1381    1247
1709    1247
1689    1782
1782    1468
1782    1316
1782    1304
1468    1101
1468    1641
1101    1641
1247    1911
1247    1501
1911    1501
1501    1934
1316    1934
1934    1304
1304    1661
1661    1025
1381    1510
1689    1510
1709    1689
1247    1381
1247    1709
1782    1689
1468    1782
1316    1782
1304    1782
1101    1468
1641    1468
1641    1101
1911    1247
1501    1247
1501    1911
1934    1501
1934    1316
1304    1934
1661    1304
1025    1661

Likes
ID1 ID2
1689    1709
1709    1689
1782    1709
1911    1247
1247    1468
1641    1468
1316    1304
1501    1934
1934    1501
1025    1101
```

I'm supposed to eliminate these 2 tuples from the likes table in the end:
1911-1247
1641-1468

They are non-reciprocal likes who are also friends

Comment: Are you using mysql or sqlite?

Comment: Do you mean, "If two students A and B are friends, and A likes B but not vice-versa, I want to remove the friends tuple."?

Comment: Use `EXISTS` and you will not make this mistake again

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work.. I edited my post to include the tables with actual values and the expected result

Comment: Can you create a Sqlfiddle for this - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were doing the Stanford Intro to SQL course for this problem, I will include my working answer. It would have been a good idea to mention that it has to work in SQlite. I am a beginner with SQL and I'm quite certain there is a more elegant solution but this should pass the automated test. Here is my solution:

```
DELETE FROM likes
WHERE likes.id1 in (Select s1.id
FROM highschooler s1, highschooler s2, friend, likes
WHERE s1.id <> s2.id
  AND friend.id1 = s1.id 
  AND friend.id2 = s2.id
  AND likes.id1 = s1.id 
  AND likes.id2 = s2.id
  AND s2.id NOT IN (SELECT s3.id FROM likes, highschooler s3, highschooler s4
                    WHERE s3.id = s2.id 
                        AND s4.id = s1.id
                        AND s3.id <> s4.id 
                        AND likes.id1 = s3.id 
                        AND likes.id2 = s4.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT * 
 FROM Likes
 where Likes.ID1 in 
               (select Likes.ID1 from Likes, Friend where Likes.ID1=Friend.ID1 and Likes.ID2=Friend.ID2) 
  AND Likes.ID1 NOT IN (SELECT Likes.ID1 FROM Likes L1, Likes L2, Friend WHERE L1.ID1=Friend.ID1 AND L2.ID2=Friend.ID2 AND L1.ID1 = L2.ID2 AND L1.ID2 = L2.ID1);
```

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work.. I edited my post to include the tables with actual values and the expected result –

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you need to repeat the Likes.ID1 field in the second AND condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Likes
where Likes.ID1 in (select Likes.ID1
                    from Likes, Friend
                    where Likes.ID1=Friend.ID1 and Likes.ID2=Friend.ID2)
  AND Likes.ID1 NOT IN (SELECT Likes.ID1
             FROM Likes L1, Likes L2, Friend
             WHERE L1.ID1=Friend.ID1
               AND L2.ID2=Friend.ID2
               AND L1.ID1 = L2.ID2
               AND L1.ID2 = L2.ID1);
```

I didn't analyse whether your query will return the right results.  This might though,

```
select *
from Likes L1
  inner join Friend on L1.ID1 = Friend.ID1
  left outer join Likes L2 on Friend.ID2 = L2.ID1 and L1.ID1 = L2.ID2
where L2.ID2 is null
```

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work.. I edited my post to include the tables with actual values and the expected result

Comment: Well, I hope you see the idea.  First find all the likes.  Then find all the friends of the liker.  Then search for all those who the friends like, including missing results this time.  Then a where clause to only return the result where the last liking was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not exactly finding the error in your query, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Likes L1
WHERE
EXISTS ( -- friendship exists
   SELECT *
   FROM Friends F 
   WHERE  F.ID1 IN (L1.ID1, L1.ID2) AND F.ID2 IN (L1.ID1, L1.ID2)
)
AND NOT EXISTS ( -- reverse like does not exist
   SELECT *
   FROM Likes L2
   WHERE L1.ID1  = L2.ID2 AND L1.ID2 =  L2.ID1
);
```

Notice that order of friends `A` and `B` in `Likes` and `Friends` can be different, so we need to `JOIN` using `IN` as I did, or `OR` statement.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work.. I edited my post to include the tables with actual values and the expected result